# help with libgil tutorial (python binding)

Tags: 3d

could you please give me some guidance on following this libgil tutorial? https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/tut-chapter0/

The problem: When I do the first example (two yellow triangles), I run in to an error with plot() saying that: display is undefined.

What I did: I followed the link to the source file (not sure what it's called in computer science...) where plot() is defined. I 'fixed' the problem by importing IPython to get display. Then new problem is, when I run the code now, I just get a printout in the console, rather than the display.[image: the plot() function]

My guess: it looks like in the decision tree of plot(), I never get to the part where the viewer is activated